# Django ManyToManyField Storing None objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create an audit app in which a model contains all the questions, answers in form of choices and comments

```
class AuditQuestion(models.Model):
    NOT_INITIATED = 'NI'
    IN_PROCESS = 'IP'
    COMPELETED = 'C'
    STATUS = (
        (NOT_INITIATED, 'Not Initiated'),
        (IN_PROCESS, 'In Process'),
        (COMPELETED, 'Completed'),
    )
    type_of_room = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfRoom, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, default=NOT_INITIATED)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

Another model contains project status which contains details of the project such as location, project_name, user and floor no of the building

```
class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
    floor_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    project_details = models.ForeignKey(ProjectDetails, null=True)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(AuditQuestion, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.floor_no)
```

The logic goes like this... a new project is created using ProjectDetails model, and a project status is generated for every floor of the building. and each floor is to be audited against the questions present in AuditQuestion model and status and comments are to be registered.

I used ManyToMany relation so that project status model can have multiple questions and their status and comments.

But, when i try to save question it doesn't happen

my view.py function is below:

```
@login_required
def save_question(request):
    project_status_id = request.POST.get('project_status_id')
    question_id = request.POST.get('question_id')
    status = request.POST.get('status')
    comments = request.POST.get('comments')
    floor_no = request.POST.get('floor_no')
    question = get_object_or_404(AuditQuestion, id=question_id)
    print (question)
    project_status, created = ProjectStatus.objects.get_or_create(id=project_status_id, floor_no=floor_no)
    project_status.save()
    project_status.question.add(question)
    print (project_status.question)
    data = {
    'status': True,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

the first print statement prints the question object correctly but the second print statement prints **audit.AuditQuestion.None**

can anyone please help me to solve this issue??

Comment: You saved before the add statement

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you try enter in the shell and look at that instance data? @Vasu Pal

Comment: try
"print (project_status.question.all())"

Comment: print (project_status.question.all()) works but how should i use to implement my login?

Answer (score 0):

After you add question to `project_status`, you don't refresh it.

add this line:

`project_status.refresh_from_db()`

before printing.

I also suggest using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).